# Angular UI: Dropdown not working with datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to add Datepicker in dropdown as follows and have set autoClose="outsideClick". However, when any month button is pressed it toggles the dropdown. How to solve this?

**Html Code:**

```
<div class="date-wrap pull-right" dropdown auto-close="outsideClick">
                <button class="btn btn-info" dropdown-toggle>Date Picker</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu  datepicker" role="menu">
                        <datepicker show-weeks="false" ng-model="dt"></datepicker>
                </div>
</div>
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/lBn3Oo?p=preview

Comment: Where is the input on which you are targeting this datepicker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to manually prevent click event from bubbling, so it never reaches the topmost node (document) that closes dropdown:

```
<div class="date-wrap pull-right" dropdown auto-close="outsideClick">
    <button class="btn btn-info" dropdown-toggle>Date Picker</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu  datepicker" role="menu" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <datepicker show-weeks="false" ng-model="dt"></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note, `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` that does the trick.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pPwW83Ro0u0g4dVhyZaZ?p=info